# System Generator: a block similar to a three state logic

Tags: fpga, xilinx, digital-logic, tri-state, xilinx-system-generator

does anyone what is the xilinx block for getting a three state logic?

Comment: could anyone create a tag called 'whatis'?

Comment: That would be a [meta-tag](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/115/2118), the use of which is discouraged.

Comment: The answer to this question is given by Martin Thompson in his answer to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10050/system-generator-how-to-make-a-channel-selector/10110#10110. I really wish you would keep strongly related topics like these in one question.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean 0/1/Z, which I assume from the tags, that's in the IOB.  Internal tri-states aren't in current FPGA families.  See the Xilinx documentation or any VHDL/Verilog book.

Specifically to answer trayres comment, there are external (IOB) tri-states, but not internal tri-states.

Comment: You said internal tri-states aren't in any current FPGA families, but in your other answer listed above you mention tri-stating the output of a mux, which would mean that there is a tri-state available in modern FPGAs. Could you specify? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're programming Verolog, use a construction like this:

```
output = (pushpull) ? logiclevel : 1'bZ;
```

where pushpull of 1'b1 states that the logiclevel (1'b1 or 1'b0) should be driven out, and pushpull of 1'b0 states the output to be of hi-z.