# System Generator: How to make a channel selector?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, hdl

I want a system with two inputs,`sel` and `in`, and at least two outputs `channel A` and `channel B`. Here's some pseudocode of what I'd like to implement:

```
if sel == 1 {
  channel_A = in;
  float_pin(channel_B); // make high impedance
}

if sel == 0 {
  channel_B = in;
  float_pin(channel_B); // make high impedance
}
```

How do I do this with Xilinx System Generator?

Answer (score 1):

Capturing the right signals simply requires an enabled flipflop.

"Float"ing is more tricky though:

There's no way of doing high-impedance internal signals in modern FPGAs, so if your outputs are connected to internal logic, you can't do that.

And although the physical pins *can* be made to tristate, as far as I can tell there's no way of accessing that from pure system generator.

To do it requires use of some FPGA tools outside of system generator:

- In your system generator model, you have to create three pins: an input, an output and an enable.
- Then wrap the system generator model in an HDL block which takes those three pins and wires them up to a suitable `IOBUF` block, which will connect to the real pin.

Comment: A visual diagram of this perform could be perfect to put this answer as a accepted. By the way thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Diagram of what particular part?

Answer (score 1):

Do a mux.  Then tristate its output.